# how to show BigPictureStyle Notification in android when app is in background while using firebase notifiaction?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using firebase notification. When app is in foreground onMessageReceived is called and Notification is visible with image (BigPictureStyle notification ). but  when app is in killed state onMessageReceived is not called and a basic notification with title and description is called .

To handle the onMessageReceived not called while app is in background i have implemented redirection logic in launcher activity (through intent bundle ).

But image is still not visible .

```
@Override
 public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        sendNotification(remoteMessage);
}
```

```
 private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Intent intent;
        if (remoteMessage != null) {
            RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();

            intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("url", url);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, REQUEST_CODE, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

            NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle BigPicstyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                    .bigPicture(bitmap_image)
                    .setBigContentTitle(title)
                    .setSummaryText(body)
                    .bigLargeIcon(null);

            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = null;


            notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID);
            if (bitmap_image != null) {
                notificationBuilder.setStyle(BigPicstyle);
                notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(bitmap_image);
            } else {
                notificationBuilder.setStyle(BigTextstyle);
                notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
            }

            //region setting notification


            notificationBuilder
                   .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(body)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setVisibility(getNotificationId())
                    .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setNumber(1)
                    .setBadgeIconType(NotificationCompat.BADGE_ICON_SMALL)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            //endregion

            getManager().notify(getNotificationId(), notificationBuilder.build());

        }


    }
```

I am getting basic notification with title and body when app is in killed state .  how can i get the image as well when app is in killed state ???

Answer (score 0):

Use fixed sized image you wants to show in notification
as below (images should not be in multiple sizes)

```
         setLargeIcon(largeIcon);  // access it from drawable folder.
```

Dont use image here from mipmap folder. it gives the appropriate resolution image.
Do the same in menifest file...

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/notification_icon_of_fixed_sized" />
<meta-data 
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
    android:resource="@color/google_blue" />
```

Comment: i want to show promotional image from server not from the mipmap or drawable